# SalesForce/Java Attach a File to an Email

Tags: salesforce, email-attachments

I am trying to attach a file/attachment related to a Document__c object and am stuck. I can get the email to send without any errors but there is no file/attachment attached to the email for some reason.
Below is the code that I am using, the commented out pieces are other variations that I've tried but also haven't worked, sorry if it's a bit messy there's a lot of commented out code. Also "" represents a line break and the continued line also starts with a "\ "Thanks for the help!

```
global class NOAemail {
    @InvocableMethod (Label='NOA Email' 
        Description='Sends the NOA email to the specified client')
    public static void SingleMail(List<flowinput> info) {

        // Create an email message object
        
        //List<Document__c> NOAdoc = [SELECT Id FROM Document__c WHERE Id=:info[0].NOAdocId];

        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

        String[] sendingTo = new String[]{info[0].address}; 

        mail.setToAddresses(sendingTo);
        
        mail.setSubject(info[0].subject);

        mail.setPlainTextBody(info[0].body);
        
        SObject[] queryParentObject = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Attachments) FROM\

              \ Document__c WHERE Id = :info[0].NOAdocId];
        for (SObject parentRecord : queryParentObject){
          Object ParentFieldValue1 = parentRecord.get('Id');       
          //Object ParentFieldValue2 = parentRecord.get('CaseNumber');   
          //Object ParentFieldValue3 = parentRecord.get('Status');
        
          // Prevent a null relationship from being accessed
          SObject[] childRecordsFromParent = parentRecord.getSObjects('Attachments');
        
          if (childRecordsFromParent != null) {
            for (SObject childRecord : childRecordsFromParent){
              //Object childFieldId = childRecord.get('Id');

              String idString = (String)childRecord.get('Id');

              //List<String> childFieldId = childRecord.get('Id');
              //Object ChildFieldValue2 = childRecord.get('Name');

              List<String> attachId = new List<String>();
              attachId.add(idString);
              mail.setEntityAttachments(attachId);
            }      
          }     
        }
        //mail.setEntityAttachments(childFieldId);
        
        /*
        List<Document__c> docs = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Attachments) FROM Document__c WHERE\

             \ Id = :info[0].NOAdocId];
        if (!docs.isEmpty()) {
        //Set<Id> attachmentIds = (new Map<Id, Document__c>(docs)).keySet();
        //Set<Id> attachmentIds = new Set<Id>();
        //attachmentIds.add(docs[0][0]);
            Set<Id> attachmentIds = (new Map<Id, SObject>(docs)).keyset();
            List<Attachment> files = [SELECT Name, Body, ContentType FROM Attachment WHERE Id IN\ 
                  \ :attachmentIds];
        }
        
        List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment> attachments = new\

             \ List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        for (Attachment file: files) {
          Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
          efa.setFileName(file.Name);
          efa.setBody(file.Body);
          efa.setContentType(file.ContentType);
          attachments.add(efa);
        }
        mail.setFileAttachments(attachments);
        */
        
        /*
        List<id> ContentDocumentIds = new List<id>();

        for(contentDocumentLink CDLink : [SELECT LinkedEntityId, ContentDocumentId FROM\

                         \ ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId=:info[0].NOAdocId])
                    {
                       ContentDocumentIds.add(CDLink.ContentDocumentId);  
                    }
                    for ( ContentVersion cversion : [SELECT Title, 
                                                            PathOnClient, FileType,
                                                            versiondata 
                                                      FROM contentversion 
                                                      WHERE ContentDocumentId IN\ 

                                                             \ :ContentDocumentIds  
                                                       AND Title LIKE 'WOCF%'])
                     {
                      blob WOCFbody = cversion.versiondata;
                      system.debug('body : '+WOCFbody+'-----------'+cversion.title);
                      Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
                      efa.setFileName('NOA Doc'+'-'+cversion.title+'.'+cversion.FileType);
                      efa.setBody(WOCFbody);
                      mail.fileAttachments.add(efa); 
                     }
        */

        /*
        List<String> contentVersionIds =  new List<String>();
        
        for(ContentDocumentLink thisCdl : [SELECT ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionId FROM\ 

                 \ ContentDocumentLink WHERE ContentDocumentId = :info[0].NOAdocId]) {
            contentVersionIds.add(thisCdl.ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionId);
        }

        mail.setEntityAttachments(contentVersionIds);
        */
        
        //SingleEmailMessage.setEntityAttachments(NOAdoc);

        //message sending

      Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail}); 

    }
    
     global class flowInput {
     
        @InvocableVariable
        global String address;
        
        @InvocableVariable
        global String subject;
        
        @InvocableVariable
        global String body;
        
        @InvocableVariable
        global String NOAdocId;
        
        //@InvocableVariable
        //global String OppAccountId;
     }

}
```

The commented out code in the code block is all code I have tried, along with the first block of code under the `mail.setPlainTextBody(info[0].body);` line.

Comment: Do you actually have `Attachment` records connected to this Document__c? In UI what's the related list's name? If it says "Files" - you have uploaded ContentDocument / ContentVersion, not the (bit old school) Attachment.

Comment: Yes I have the pdf stored in both the "Files" and "Notes & Attachments" related lists for the Document__c. I thought that was my problem but after adding it to the "Notes & Attachments" it still doesn't work.